# Data Binding and throwing exception in setter

Tags: .net, winforms, data-binding, exception, setter

Let's say I have a simple class

```
public class Person
{
  public string Name { get; set; }

  private int _age;
  public int Age
  {
    get { return _age; }
    set
    {
      if(value < 0 || value > 150)
        throw new ValidationException("Person age is incorrect");
      _age = value;
    }
  }
}
```

Then I want to setup a binding for this class:

```
txtAge.DataBindings.Add("Text", dataSource, "Name");
```

Now if I enter incorrect age value in the text box (say 200) the exception in the setter will be swallowed and I will not be able to do anything at all until I correct the value in the textbox. I mean the textbox will not be able to loose focus. It's all silent - no errors - you just can't do anything (even close the form or the whole application) until you correct the value.

It seems like a bug, but the question is: what is a workaround for this?

Comment: Is there a reason you're throwing an exception rather than implementing IDataErrorInfo? I think the latter is the more idiomatic approach in WinForms (and it still works nicely in WPF too).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, here is the solution:

We need to handle BindingComplete event of BinsingSource, CurrencyManager or BindingBanagerBase class.  The code can look like this:

```
/* Note the 4th parameter, if it is not set, the event will not be fired. 
It seems like an unexpected behavior, as this parameter is called 
formattingEnabled and based on its name it shouldn't affect BindingComplete 
event, but it does. */
txtAge.DataBindings.Add("Text", dataSource, "Name", true)
.BindingManagerBase.BindingComplete += BindingManagerBase_BindingComplete;

...

void BindingManagerBase_BindingComplete(
  object sender, BindingCompleteEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Exception != null)
  {
    // this will show message to user, so it won't be silent anymore
    MessageBox.Show(e.Exception.Message); 
    // this will return value in the bound control to a previous correct value
    e.Binding.ReadValue();
  }
}
```

Comment: huuh ... think about implementing IDataErrorInfo

Comment: @PeterGfader  I've seen examples where `IDataErrorInfo` is implemented on a business object.  But I don't think that such approach is quite right.  Imagine, for example that a model has got 2x views attached to it.  Both views share the same implementation of the `IDataErrorInfo`.  The first view has got invalid input data.  The second one has got valid data.  But the `IDataErrorInfo` implementation can't "know" which view it belongs to.  The interface doesn't define such connection.  So, I think that ViewModels should implement `IDataErrorInfo`, not the business objects.