# Misused Nullable type doesn't throw an error in exe

Tags: vb.net

A project I'm looking at contains this code:

```
Private _ddate As Date?
Property ddate() As Date
    Get
        Return _ddate
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Date)
        _ddate = value.Date  
    End Set
End Property
```

Note the backing field is nullable, but the property isn't! 
The object of which this is a part, is initialised and bound to a form. The _ddate field is not touched in the initialisation code. Running in Debug mode, this throws an error - 'nullable object must have a value'. That's what I would expect. 
However, the compiled version 'just works'. No errors. How can this be? What am I missing?

Comment: There's not nearly enough details here.

Comment: @Sam Difficult to add more without pasting the whole project!

Comment: That wont compile under `Option Strict`.  A `Date?` is not a `Date` as the  assignment in the getter tries to do.

Comment: @Plutonix Of course you are right, but if I enable Option Strict on this old clunker of a project I will enter a whole other world of hurt. I'm hoping someone else has seen this behaviour and can identify why it works perfectly when compiled.

Comment: Are you sure it's working perfectly?  It could be that it's still throwing an exception, but there is release-only code that is catching and eating the exception.

Comment: @peterG: don't turn it on for the project, turn it on for any file you edit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how data binding works. If accessing the bound property's getter or setter raises an exception, it is suppressed, but you can [observe it from a `BindingComplete` event handler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/882231/11683).

There is nothing special about the nullable backing field in this regard. You can achieve the same result by replacing the contents of the `Property Get` with `Throw New Exception`.

Documentation with examples: [How to: Handle Errors and Exceptions that Occur with Databinding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-handle-errors-and-exceptions-that-occur-with-databinding)