# How to handle exceptions that occur during databinding in newer versions of .NET (above 3.5)?

Tags: .net, winforms, validation, data-binding, exception

I'm following this example from MSDN
[Handle errors and exceptions that occur with databinding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k26k86tb(v=vs.85).aspx/css) ([same example also here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-handle-errors-and-exceptions-that-occur-with-databinding))

The idea behind this example:

1. TextBox controls are bound to the business object properties using `BindingSource` and `Binding` objects.  The business object is the Model.
2. The property setters in the business object validate the inputs and throw exceptions when inputs are invalid.
3. The binding objects are configured to catch such exceptions.
4. The binding fires the `BindingComplete` event.  If there was an exception, it was caught, and the exception message is available through `BindingCompleteEventArgs`.  The validation error messages can trickle back to the presentation layer that way.

So far - so good.

Here's the odd part.  The catching of the exception thrown by the business object varies for different versions of .NET .

- This works with .NET version 3.5 . The binding framework catches the exception. `BindingComplete` event is fired. The event arguments indicate that binding was not successful. As expected.
- The .NET versions 4.0, 4.5, 4.5.2 don't catch the exception in the Model's property setter. The execution breaks on that exception.

The same source code copypasted from the Microsoft's example.  I only change the version of .NET in the project properties.

- What has changed in the newer versions of .NET so that this example stopped working as expected?
- Is there a way to make this work with newer versions of .NET ?  Is the example missing a setting which was introduced in the newer versions of .NET?

#### Appendix A: Related reading and prior art

A similar approach has also been proposed in this earlier thread: [Data Binding and throwing exception in setter (2009)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/880357/data-binding-and-throwing-exception-in-setter)

A [thread on MSDN forum (2010)](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/459d17ac-6f34-468b-9ddd-b15d1aae926c/bindingsource-and-validating-event) which suggests to throw an exception in a  `Binding.Parse` event.
[Curiously, a data binding occurs even if `e.Cancel` is set to `true` in a Control.Validating event handler.  Is that a feature?]

#### Appendix B: Preemptive responses to anticipated comments

> Using exceptions for user input validation isn't great.

I agree.  At the same time, the property setters in a model have to validate parameters and throw exceptions if parameter is garbage. Can't have a model which accepts invalid parameters.

Having said that, I'm open to other ideas too.  Is there some other way for the model to do the input validation and send validation error information to the presentation?

> That example is WinForms.  Why don't you use WPF?

I'm using WinForms because of legacy.

Comment: "The .NET versions 4.0, 4.5, 4.5.2 don't catch the exception in the Model's property setter." -- I think you meant: "The .NET versions 4.0, 4.5, 4.5.2 catch the exception in the Model's property setter."  That said, it appears as though it is a change in unhandled exception handling with the debugger attached.  If you clear the "break when this exception type is user-unhandled" box, you will get the same behavior as 3.5.  If you run without the debugger attached, the behavior is the same regarless of .Net version.

Comment: @TnTinMn  I didn't know that Visual Studio distinguishes between *unhandled* and *user-unhandled*.  I've read [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2015/01/07/understanding-exceptions-while-debugging-with-visual-studio/) and [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x85tt0dd.aspx).  You've pointed me in a right direction.  If you make an answer out of your comment, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a difference in what is classified as a *user-unhandled* exception in .Net 3.5 and .Net 4+. This change may not have occurred with .Net 4.0 as .Net 4.5+ are in-place replacements for .Net 4.

Consider the following configuration for the `System.Exception` that is thrown in the subject code's property setter. The following images were captured from VS2013.  VS2015+ use a different exception settings dialog (see: [The New Exception Settings Window in Visual Studio 2015](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2015/02/23/the-new-exception-settings-window-in-visual-studio-2015/)).  To see the *user-unhandled* option, you need to enable "Just-My-Code" debugging.

[image]

[image]

When compiled against .Net 4.7, the debugger will break when the exception is thrown.  However, when compiled against .Net 3.5, the debugger will not break when the exception is thrown.

If you clear the "break when this exception type is user-unhandled" box, you will get the same behavior as 3.5. If you run without the debugger attached, the behavior is the same regardless of .Net version.